# Database Design for basic CMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a basic CMS for a small academic project I want to use to practice design patterns in code later and I am starting with designing the database.

The simple requirement is that a "Container" of some kind will contain "Pages" or "Controls". Also a "Page" will contain "Controls". Think of a container like the holder for several tabbed pages. So when something is saved, everything can be saved at once by simply calling save on the container.

Anyway, I have 3 tables. "Container", "Page" and "Control".

Think of a "Container" like a holder for all the things that will appear on screen. It can be split into other smaller containers if needed (for wide screen).

Think of a "Page" like a form of some kind. Something that will allow the user to place controls used to collect data.

Think of a "Control" like a label, text box, button, etc. There are various types of controls (not shown in the diagram), but the "Controls" table will hold multiple instances of any given control type. For example, a form that has 5 labels and 5 text boxes, will have 10 corresponding entries in the controls table - 5 entries for each type of control. So a control is a singular instance of a control type, will have a unique ID, and can only be used once.

If a container is deleted, I want this to cascade and delete the relevant pages and controls.

Likewise, if a page is deleted, I want this to cascade and delete the controls that were on that page.

I have 2 problems to solve.

Problem 1: A control can belong to either a container or a page, but not both. Essentially a control can have only one owner or parent. Likewise with a page. However with a control, because it can be put on either a container, or a page, I have to connect it with 2 relationships, and create a constraint on the PageId and ControlId columns that ensures only one of them is not null. This I have done successfully, but I am wondering if there is a better way?

Problem 2: Because I am using cascade update and delete with 3 tables. I am getting an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Pages_Containers' on table
>   'Pages' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE
>   NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

I want the controls belonging to a page or container, AND the pages belonging to a container deleted if either the page or container is deleted. So, in my mind, I need the cascading update and delete. So this error is forcing me to change my relationship requirements in a way that will leave orphans.

As a side note, a container could also contain other containers. This might be useful on large wide screens to display a form (page) in two parts, one on the left and one on the right for example, and still be able to save everything by clicking a save button on the parent.

So how can I overcome this? Am I overlooking something in my design?

For clarity here is an ER diagram:

[image]

You can see from the stars (*) that it is not saved yet because of the above error. My first goal is to get the database right. I don't like entity framework code first, and I want to use either entity framework database first or an alternative ORM that does it's thing as needed. But I want data integrity handled by the database where it should be.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can't you simplify that? A page can only have containers. And only containers can have controls. Sure, that may cause to be forced to use containers of one control. But like that it's a strict hierarchy, easy to understand and your multiple cascade path problem is solved.

Comment: I think we are confusing terms but I get the concept. A page is like a small form or a single tab of a tabbed set of pages. So they are contained within a container. The purpose of this is so I can place a save button on the main container, and ensure all data on every page, in every control is saved with a single click. If I were to restrict a container to only contain pages, and a page to only contain controls, it would solve the problem. But it would not be very flexible. Imagine the code that would have to be written to ensure everything in a set of containers was saved for example.

Comment: Is it possible for you to separate relation tables instead of keeping relations in same tables? We can achieve by creating Master tables, Child Tables and Relation Tables.

Comment: Its an very interesting idea. Would this concept still allow for data integrity to be handled by the database or would it require the saving of relational data to be performed in code and therefore pass the management of what should be a database problem to become a code problem? If it is possible to keep it within the database, its definitely something I would like to explore more. Given the above, which would be a master table, and a child, and where do you see relation table being used?

Comment: Actually that is interesting me more. For example, the controls table would be a master table, the pages table would be a child table, and we just create a ControlsPagesRelation table. Its one extra table to manage the relationship. Doing this would also allow the user to create relationships between their data easier and possible lead to the beginning of a simple rules engine in some way. Do I understand your concept correctly? If so, we would need a table for every relationship. So one between Pages and controls also. Or would a single relationship table be able to manage all relationships?

Comment: Control can have Container or Page as a parent but not both right? In your Control table ContainerParent and PageTitle both columns are there.

Comment: If you can maintain Master Source table then It may resolve. For eg. Source_Type table with master data as 1. Container and 2. Page. Source_Master table will have Source_Id, Source_Type_Id. Source_Id you can use as parent in Container table, Page table as well as Control table. You need to generate entry in Source_Master table 1st and use that id in Container, Page and Control. If you delete from Source_Master corresponding records from other 3 tables also will get deleted

Comment: This is right. Because for example, a control type of label, might have 5 label instances, but each instance can exist in only one place, either a container or a page. You could not have the same instance in several places. Perhaps the "Controls" table should be named "ControlInstances" for clarity. - However I am not sure I understand the second comment, can you explain a little more please?

Comment: If you can generate unique ids between Container and Pages in some 3 table ie. Source_Master and use that id as ContainerId, ContainerParentId in Container table, Page, PageParentId in page table, ControlParentId in Control table.

Comment: So I create a Source_Type table with PK-Id, ContainerId, PageId, ControlId. Next I create a Source_Master table with Source_Type_Id which is a FK to the Source_Type table. In the Source_Master table I also have a PK column called Source_Id. I then relate via FK relationships in the Controls, Pages and Container pages to the Source_Type table. All relationshps are cascade types. So when I delete an id in the Source Master table, it cascades to the Source_Type and on to the rest of the tables. Do I understand correctly? Its not working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments under the question. I tried a few solutions. Here is one that I came up with that seems to work best so far. I am just posting this for my own reference later, and maybe it will help others. So I still welcome any other suggestions for improvement.

To start I removed all the relationships and created a container type table. This I linked to a container manager table. Then I lined the container and pages table with a 1:1 relationship to the container management table. The logic behind this was that I currently have 2 types of containers, but later I could add more if I wanted.

In the container types I added data for "Container" and "Page" then referenced this back to the container manager table. I added an additional field in the container manager table to show who the parent of the container or page was. This is a self referencing relationship. It simplified the container and pages table somewhat.

Next I repeated the process with the controls table. It was slightly more complicated but the same idea. It just split containers from controls very nicely and then let the management tables link up to "manage" things.

From there it was simply a matter of adding a container parent to the control manager table and relating it back to the container manager table. All the relationships are cascading and work without problems. As you can see, the management tables, combined with the 1:1 relationships to controls, containers, and pages tables, provide instance specific information allowing for easy management. I really like that I don't have to build any constraints like I had in my original solution to ensure only one of 2 fields were filled in as constraints are not obvious. However, I have noticed that I could technically just combine the data from the linked 1:1 tables directly into the management tables and simplify the diagram even more. Which I may yet do as it is easier and faster to look at 2 tables, than 5. I would be interested to hear peoples opinion of this.

[image]

The general use case would be that we know the types of containers or controls in advance. So we can select the type of controls we want to put on a page or container. This information adds data to the management tables and generates a unique Id for the instance of the container, page, or control being used. Then we use that Id to create the actual container, page, or control instance the user will see. Obviously saving the data behind the controls is another matter that is not part of the question so I wont go into my solution for that here.

Thanks to D Mayuri who inspired this approach with is help and comments about separating out the relationships. I am not sure if this is how he intended me to do it. If he posts his own answer, I will of course accept and give him credit.